# Printer.print to text document in VB6

Tags: printing, vb6

Im not 100% about this, so bear with me and hopefully you can help me make sense and solve the issue.

So in my code there are a lot of printer.print "Some String" and right at the end, like there should be, is a printer.enddoc.

Occasionally we get an issue where, for what ever reason, the printer isnt ready and crashes the software out with an error 482 which basically means the printer isnt ready.

What I want to do is push the document that will be printed into a text file before printing so if there is an issue, the document isnt lost, and it also helps with saving data to be reprinted at a later date.

I assumed (wrongly, I think) that printer.print pushes data into something that will be fired to the printer and can be viewed before hand, but I am not convinced.

I want to just clarify that the code I am working on is at least 15 years old, been played with by at least 5 different coders and its all a bit of a jumble.

Comment: what about using a pdf printer and then print from adobe or foxit?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you defined is exactly what print spoolers, or "printers" (a.k.a. printer drivers) are designed to handle through Windows.  Except for the ability to reprint at a later time.  Any failed document should still be in your printer's queue, and can be restarted from there, so there should be no loss in that sense.  If you want to have reports stored in a file format, as in the comments, it's been suggested you can print to a PDF file.  In my accounting system I use various methods, including Crystal Reports, direct-to-printer, and direct-to-pdf.  If you want something more complex than just manually handling it through the print queue, you may have to re-design the report structure, or purchase a third-party set of utilities.  Component-One includes lots of printer stuff in their Active-X package including print-preview, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Show the code you use to print.

You are using a Error Handler ?

Your code check if printer is ready, before to print?